# How to display only one category posts on main page?

Tags: plugins

How do I make sure that articles from certain category do not display on main page?

I want them to display on a subpage only.

So let's say I have 7 articles under "main".

I want all of these to display on main page, homepage.

Then let's say I have 20 articles on "category1".

I want them all to display in website.com/category1 but not on main page.

Comment: I removed the request for plugins as that would get your question closed as offtopic. This is a developer stack so you should expect a technical answer. If it was a recommendation you wanted you should ask on the software recommendations stack instead

Answer (score 1):

Example of a function to remove post category from the home page.

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-5, -34' );
        }
    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

Replace the category ID with the one you want to exclude. Add to functions.php of your child theme.